# How to insert values of a whole column in python using xlwt

Tags: python, excel

I have found the intersection of two columns in the same excel sheet and I would like to write the result in a third column in the same sheet using xlwt, how do I do it? I post the code I am working with below.

```
import xlrd
import xlwt


wb=xlrd.open_workbook('try2.xls')
xlsname = 'try2.xls'
book = xlrd.open_workbook(xlsname, on_demand=True)
sheet0=book.sheet_by_name('one')
A = sheet0.col(0)
B = sheet0.col(1)
C = sheet0.col(2)
D = sheet0.col(3)
E = sheet0.col(4)
F = sheet0.col(5)
W = E and F
```

How do I write W in `G = sheet0.col(6)`? Thanks!!

Comment: You can't update the sheet in place... You use `xlwt` to create a new workbook and a new sheet and write the existing columns and new column. Plenty of examples of how to do that in the tutorial/intro/xlwt examples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It impossible set formula for one column at 'one string'. You can write code similar to below:

```
import xlwt as xl

doc = xl.Workbook() #Create document
#Add a worksheet
sheet = doc.add_sheet("Some Sheet")
for i in range(100):
    #Write 2 columns
    sheet.write(i, 0, i+1) 
    sheet.write(i, 1, i*2)
    #Write result (SUM for example)
    sheet.write(i, 2, xl.Formula("SUM(A%d:B%d)" % (i+1, i+1)))
doc.save("my_table.xls")
```

Answer (score 1):

HOW to insert a column before specified column in excel sheet using python

```
    import win32com.client
    xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
```

Open excel sheet

```
    wkbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Sunil\\myexcel.xlsx")
```

Activcate the sheet you want by number

```
    wksht = wkbk.Sheets(1)
```

Activcate the sheet you want by name

```
    wksht = wkbk.Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate()

    wksht = wkbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate()
```

Take the object of activated sheet

```
    wksht = wkbk.ActiveSheet;
```

insert column before Column B

```
    wksht.Columns("B").EntireColumn.Insert()
```

Comment: The OP is about using xlwt. This solution only works on Windows, and only if you have Excel.